# Since math is a minimalistic science, what's the idea of defining such a thing like cosecant or secant?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

As we all know, math is a minimalistic science. For example we don't put into the definition of differentiable functions that they have to be continuous. So my question is this:

> What's the idea of defining such a thing like cosecant  or secant?  I have never seen their use in math or other science.

Comment: it is a useful notation abbreviation sometimes

Comment: It would be interesting to see in which "mathematical geographical areas" sec and cosec are still used. For example, in France, they aren't used, and as far as I know they have never been used.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how they are defined then:
$$\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$
and $$\csc(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(x)}$$

If you're asking when the are used, almost everything in higher level math or physics relies on some knowledge of trigonometry. For example, when you take a Complex Analysis Class, knowledge of trigonometric functions is heavily used.

Comment: I think OP means that these specific names $sec$ and $csc$ are not really used, we usually write $\frac{1}{cosx}$ and $\frac{1}{sinx}$ instead. And he is right. I never used $sec$ and $csc$, these names only confuse me. Defining sine, cosine and tangent is enough for everything.